# Coding PHP extensions in Cpp

Tags: g++, php-extension

I am trying to code PHP extensions in C++. I am referring 'Embedding and Extending PHP' by Sara Golemon.

The book has several small snippets as such,

```
void describe_zval(zval *foo)
{
    if (Z_TYPE_P(foo) == IS_NULL) {
        php_printf("The variable is NULL");
    } else {
        php_printf("The variable is of type %d",
                            Z_TYPE_P(foo));
    }
}
```

**I have saved the above code in .cpp**

The struct `zval` etc is defined in files in `/usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/` and its sub -directories. That is the installation directory of PHP on my PC [Fedora]. So I tried

`#include <zend.h>`

and used `-I /usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/` while compiling. But zend.h seems to require some other file present in `/usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/` directory. If i #include that it requires some others and so on... Basically a chain of .h is being called which resides in several different sub directories of `/usr/local/src/php-5.4.11/` . Its not possible for me to #include all of them. Is there any existing library for this? using Zend variables for PHP extension development using  Cpp

Is there a better way to do this? I mean is there a better way to practise those small snippets before i jump into the whole extension development.

Comment: Perhaps using `phpize` will be useful?

Comment: @Waleed Khan: Thnks, Ohkk so i need to use phpize. Yes, dat makes sense :) after all what I am doing is writing a small snippet for a PHP extension.

Have been thinking in the wrong direction the whole time :P

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at the ext-skel directory? there should be a script there to generate an extension skelleton which should get you started.

Comment: Yeps that would be helpful too